# "Even simpler is the utility egrep" -- how do you understand it?

Tags: meaning

From the book *Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition*:

> Finding text is one of the simplest uses of regular expressions—many text editors and word processors allow you to search a document using a regular-expression pattern. **Even simpler is the utility egrep**.

How do you understand the last sentence? Does it mean that this program makes it even easier to find text?

Comment: This is just a bit of sentence inversion to bring the focus of the sentence to the front. You can remove the inversion to get: "The utility [called] egrep is even simpler."

Comment: Or s/\\([a-zE]*\\) \\([a-z]*\\) \\([a-z]*\\) \\([a-z]*\\) \\([a-z]*\\) \\([a-z]*\\)/\4 \5 \6 \3 \1 \2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not worded very well, but I believe you are correct that it means "egrep makes it even easier to find text than an editor or word processor."

If I were writing the passage, I might phrase it:

> Finding text is one of the simplest uses of regular expressions. Many text editors and word processors allow you to search a document for text using a regular-expression pattern. An even simpler way to find text that matches a pattern is the utility egrep.

Comment: I contend that it's not worded *badly*; in fact, in my opinion, it's concise and elegant.

Comment: @PrimeMover  The simplest use of regex is finding text. Even simpler is the utility egrep. The only reason you think that is concise and elegant is because you already understand what the author is trying to say. What “simpler” is referring back to is not “finding text” but “uses of regex”. It’s poorly written.